# Geometry ( dividing a circumference in 360 equal parts)

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to divide a circumference 360 shares using only ruler and compass? That is, the former (ancients) did so (like this) ? To my knowledge it is possible through exact processes divide it into 2,4,8 .... 3,6,12,24 ... or 5,10,20,40..then, how? if it's impossible, trisect (divide in 3)  an angle in equal parts using only ruler and compass, for what I know 360 has 3 as a divisor..so is it possible ?

Comment: No...you can't even construct the regular 9-sided polygon exactly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon

Comment: Yeah exactly i thout this too..so how the ancients ( people of past, greeks, babilons) did?

Comment: No. It is possible to construct a 3 degree angle by bisecting angles you get from constructible regular n-gons with $n=3,5$. As Lulu said 1 degrees (or 2) is impossible.

Comment: The ancients were apparently happy with an approximation or they used tools other than ruler and compass, when they needed things like large scale protractors for astronomy and/or navigation.

Comment: Our deegre is actualy a "real" measure or not? So, nowadays, our "deegre" is exact?

Comment: @COSTAPHY If you allow trisections it is possible, and there are several so-called neusis techniques which allow for that, see (eg) http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/archi.shtml .  So it isn't a huge stretch from being constructible.  I don't think we share the classical notion that "exact" is the same as "constructible".  After all, we even tolerate things like $\pi$ or $e$ without calling them "inexact".

Comment: Thank you guys, i love math and science...greetings from Brazil!!

Answer (score 1):

If you allow **neusis** see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection you can trisect angles. Drawing a regular pentagon by ruler and compass is no problem, and likewise you can bisect angles.

Comment: Origami also allows trisections. If there is a hyperbola, and the intersections with the hyperbola are allowed, angles can be constructed eith a compass and straightedge.

Answer (score 0):

If a 1 degree angle can be constructed by this method, so can the 20 degree angle, contradicting Pierre Wantzel's result.

So the answer is no.